# NFS4 client add more threads

Tags: mount, nfs

I know how to add threads on an NFS4 server, `RPCNFSDCOUNT` in vim `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server`. [This page from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1450/chapter3-3.html#chapter3-33) says that:

> Controls the number of kernel threads that perform asynchronous I/O
>   for the NFS version 4 client. Because NFS is based on RPC and RPC is
>   inherently synchronous, separate execution contexts are required to
>   perform NFS operations that are asynchronous from the calling thread.

So, I edit `/etc/system` as root, and set the flag as follows:

```
set nfs:nfs4_max_threads = 650
```

but it doesn't show by checking `sysctl -a | grep nfs` and other attempts like editing `/etc/nfs.conf` and adding

```
nfs.client.nfsiod_thread_max = 650
```

do nothing also.

How can I set this and verify that it is set?

Comment: did you unmount and mount again after changing the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

thats the solaris manual not the linux one!

Theres no thread tunable up to kernel 3.10 at least.

Have a look at what is available to you with this:
  sysctl -a | grep nfs

And some other related recommendations here:
https://dhelios.blogspot.com/2016/07/nfs-mount-options.html

If you find a way to increase threads - or some other way max data rate to an NFS share from a single client beyond some seemingly 4-500MB/s limit - I'd be interested.